# Удовлетворяет ли код БЭМ?

Tags: html, вёрстка, бэм

Всем привет, господа фронтенды, подскажите, удовлетворяет ли код соглашению по наименованию БЭМ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ВЫГОДНОЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table class=main>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table class="main__header">
          <tr>
            <td class="main__header-td">
              <a href="" class="main__header-item">Главная</a>
              <a href="" class="main__header-item main__header-item_logo">Ваш логотип</a>
              <a href="" class="main__item">Мой аккаунт</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="main__navigation-table">
          <tr>
            <td class="main__navigation">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="main__blackfriday">
          <tr>
            <td class="main__blackfriday-td">
              <img src="" alt="" class="main__blackfriday-stand">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Dmitry Спасибо, исправил!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В целом удовлетворяет, по ссылке https://yoksel.github.io/html-tree/ можно посмотреть дерево документа на основе HTML-разметки. Бонусом делается простая проверка БЭМ-классов и иерархии заголовков.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Не знал, что для БЭМа тоже есть валидаторы)